# cron.yaml GCP testing locally

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to test the cron.yaml (App Engine) locally?

Thanks

I see that GCP CLI has a dev_appserver.py to test the app using app.yaml, but I'm interested in cron.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set up a cron job, you provide a URL to be called at a specified time.

You can create a test that calls that URL (e.g., using dev_appserver.py) and then make sure that the operations are performed correctly.

I don't see anything else you need to test so I don't think there is a need for Google to provide any emulator relating to cron jobs.